# What happened to the Belt of Beloth the Wise?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

During the siege of Dras-Leona, Eragon loses the belt after the confrontation with the priests of Helgrind. He fails at finding the belt at that time and he still couldn't find the belt when he went to check for it later.

Any idea what happened to it? Was the wards around it so powerful, nobody could ever find if it was lost? Or did someone destroy the belt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We don't know, but it'll probably be in book five (or a different book)

> **So it’s safe to say that any “loose ends” we may come across are intended for future tales? Such as, perhaps, the belt of Beloth the Wise?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Possibly. The problem is, there are* always *loose ends. If I write another story, it’ll probably raise as many questions as it answers. Still, yes, the belt of Beloth the Wise will pop up again somewhere else. Personally, my favorite theory is that Angela swiped it in Dras-Leona. But then again, I can’t imagine she would have done anything to harm Eragon’s chances of killing Galbatorix.*
>
> <sub>[Shurtagal.com's first post-Inheritance interview with Christopher Paolini, December 2011](http://www.shurtugal.com/2011/12/10/first-post-inheritance-interview-with-christopher-tackles-book-4s-hot-topics-and-more/)</sub>
>
> **So what became of the belt of Beloth the Wise?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Heh. Book V.*
>
> <sub>[Twitter AMA October 2012](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/261637472079978498?s=19)</sub>
>
> **Where did the belt of Beloth the Wise go?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Great question. No comment.*
>
> **Is it potentially important? ‘Pay attention to it, readers,’ type thing?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Well it’s not unimportant. I mean, a big magical artifact suddenly disappearing for a while, that’s cause for concern, yes.*
>
> **Well you say “for a while,” so it might reappear at some point.**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *That’s right, it might.*
>
> <sub>[Shurtagal.com's second post-Inheritance interview with Christopher Paolini, January 2013](http://www.shurtugal.com/2013/08/17/new-interview-we-talk-some-major-post-inheritance-information-with-christopher-including-dragons-eggs-angela-tenga-murtagh-and-more/)</sub>
>
> **What happen with the belt of Beloth the Wise?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Good question.*
>
> <sub>[Twitter June 2015](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/610482377278623744?s=19)</sub>
>
> **Since Bregan could see Murtagh’s eldunari and the belt of Beloth the wise…could he possibly find the belt?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Yup.*
>
> <sub>[Twitter December 2015](https://www.paolini.net/2015/12/23/qas-outlining-stories/)</sub>
>
> **Eragon used the Name of Names trying to find [the belt], if I recall correctly, so do we assume that it's been destroyed?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *Never assume anything.*
>
> <sub>[Facebook AMA February 2017](https://www.facebook.com/PaoliniOfficial/posts/1565802433465004?comment_id=1565809523464295&reply_comment_id=1565822890129625)</sub>

Comment: It's worth noting that when Paolin revised *Inheritance* for the Deluxe edition he added a few short passages about Bregan. I think it's very likely that he'll be involved in whatever story the belt turns up in.

Answer (score 0):

Angela could have taken it. She has lived for so long and knows so much, maybe she knew a way to hide it where magic, even the name of names, could not find it. If you say that angela would not harm his chances against Galbatorix by taking it, remember, she is wierd. Bregan could have taken it because he can see energy. Spirits could have taken it to another dimention where they live, because even the name of names can't find it, and because spirits eat energy.